# Angular 2 interpolation

Tags: angular

I'm trying to render different values from a json through interpolation but for some reason it only works inside an iteration.

For example:

```
<ul>
   <li *ngFor="let object of objects">
       {{object.title}} {{object.text}}
   </li>
</ul>
```

This works.

But whenever I want to access a specific value without iterating it doesn't work:

```
{{objects[0].title}} {{objects[0].text}}
```

Getting this error: ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Any idea why this happens?

Thanks!

Comment: can you show us your component code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm willing to bet you aren't setting a value for `objects` initially. Your code probably looks something like this.

```
@Component({
...
})
class MyComponent {
   objects;
   ngOnInit () {
       someHttpRequest().then((res) => objects = res);
   }
}
```

Angular will try to interpolate `objects` as soon as the component loads, and since you aren't giving objects a value until after that `objects[0]` is, in fact, undefined.

You can fix this in a couple ways - probably the easiest is just to wrap any `object[0]` references in an `*ngIf`

```
<div *ngIf="objects && objects.length > 0">
    {{objects[0].foo}}
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought the problem was something like that, knowing that the json response comes from an external api. But the correct rendering with iteration was very missleading... I still don't get how does that work. If the object is undefined it should also be undefined inside the iteration...
Anyways, thanks, it worked great!

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer would be,

```
{{Objects[0]?.title}} {{objects[0]?.text}}
```